# Opening the project in vivado

Tags: tcl, xilinx, vivado

I need to work on a repository which is in a Git, I want to know how to work with a project inside the repo in the vivado? I googled it and found that I need to address ".tcl" file in command terminal but, in my "sample project" folder there are multiple ".tcl" files so I got confused if I need to add all of them or not.

Answer (score 2):

Vivado is NOT git friendly and you will need to go several hoops to get it even tolerable.

First, generate tcl script to regenerate the project:

> write_project_tcl create_project.tcl

This file can go to git and can be used to generate the project after a clean clone. To be noted that this is *not* the project file, it's a script that can re-generate the project. So running it every time a project parameter changes is quite cumbersome, and often leads to situation where local projects veers off from the "template" project in git.

Another problem is Vivado generated IP. Fortunately most often you need only the .xci file from the generated files to be stored in git. Unfortunately, by default these are generated as part of the project files, which should **not** go to git. I would recommend putting the generated IP to some other folder outside the project-structure. Vivado will fight against you on this, but mostly it's worth it.